# Installing seaborn and additional packages in Spyder environment

Tags: python, seaborn, conda, spyder

I keep trying to install seaborn in Spyder environment on my Mac using 'conda install seaborn' in Spyder terminal but I get the following error -

```
Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
ImportError: bad magic number in 'site': b'a\r\r\n'
```

Is there any guide on how to install any new modules in Spyder?